# Does it follow that $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ is bounded in every bounded interval $I\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ if $f$ is continuous in $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was trying to solve a bigger exercise and I thought of the following

> **Conjecture**
>
> Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ be continuous in $\Bbb R^n$. Then $f$ is bounded in every bounded interval $I\subseteq \Bbb R^n$.

Which could be useful. I think this is true, but I'm not quite sure how to prove this, I'm mostly interested in the case $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, but the generalization would be nice if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What is an "interval" in $\mathbb{R}^n$?  A product of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes,  in this case a cartesian product of *bounded* $\Bbb R$ intervals.

Comment: You may use the fact that a continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets, and compact is equivalent to closed and bounded in Euclidean space

Comment: @FrankLu But the interval may be $(0,1)$, which is not compact, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD But $[0,1]$ is compact, then the image $f([0,1])$ is compact, which clearly implies $f((0,1))$ is compact. In general, if $f$ is bounded on the closed interval, then obviously it is bounded on the open interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is any bounded set, then $f(A)$ is bounded.  This follows from the fact that a continuous image of a compact set is compact: if $A$ is bounded, then $\overline{A}$ is closed and bounded and hence compact, so $f(\overline{A})$ is compact and hence bounded, so $f(A)\subseteq f(\overline{A})$ is also bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more "analytic" proof is this:

Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=\Vert f(x)\Vert$, which is a composition of continuous functions, so it is continuous . We easily see $f \text{ bounded on }I\Leftrightarrow g \text{ bounded on }I$

To prove $g$ bounded on $I$, first, assume $I$ is closed (so it is compact). Consider a sequence $(x_k)_k$ with $x_k\in I$, s.t. $g(x_k)\to S:=\sup_{x\in I} g(x)$.

Since $x_k\in I$ which is a compact set, it has a convergent subsequence $x_{l_k}\to \bar{x}\in I$. By continuity, $g(x_{l_k})\to g(\bar{x})$. This shows $S=g(\bar{x})<\infty$, so $g$ is bounded on $I$.

If $I$ is not closed, still $\bar{I}$ is closed and bounded, so compact. Using $0\leq \sup_{x\in I} g(x)\leq \sup_{x\in \bar{I}} g(x)$ and the previous argument, we see $g$ is bounded on $I$.

Then again, Eric's proof is better in the sense that it is valid for more general topological spaces.